# L' « apprenant » : autres recréations modernes bien connues au parcours semblable ?

Tags: usage, histoire, terminologie

Dans le domaine de l'*éducation*, on a le terme « [*apprenant*](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=apprenant) » (2009)<sup>1</sup> :

> apprenant, -e, **n.** *langage professionnel*
>   Toute personne, de l'enfant à l'adulte, engagée dans un processus
>   d'acquisition de connaissances et de compétences.
>
> [ *FranceTerme* - site consacré aux termes recommandés au *Journal
>   officiel de la République française*. - « *apprenant* » ]

Il faut remonter à un français bien plus [ancien](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/apprendre?idf=dmfXdXrmXabgbd;str=0)<sup>2</sup> pour le retrouver comme substantif avant le 20/21<sup>e</sup>:

> V. - Part. prés. en empl. subst. "Apprenti" : *Aprenant* que sont
>   lowez. Jugement (...) d'un enffans que li peire mist a mestier delei
>   ung taillour a .IIII. ans, le quel enffans s'en allat fuer du paiis et
>   ne savoit on qu'il fut devenus, se volloit li peire que li maistre li
>   randit son enffans, por tant qu'il disoit que le maistre et cez
>   maigniez l'avoient sormonner ; le maistre disoit que non et qu'il en
>   avoit bien fait son debvoir. (*Jug. maître-échev. Metz* S.M.S., t.1,
>   a.1494, 1343], 219). Luiers d'*aprenant*. Jugement de Jehan, de
>   Raucourt, le ferbour, d'une pairt, et des maistres et des jurei des
>   ferbour d'autre pairt, pour ce que lesdits maistres et jureis
>   volloient que ledit Jehan paiest entree a mestier pour ung aprenant
>   qu'il avoit. Li maistre-eschevin dit pour droict qu'il n'en avoit
>   point a paier. (*Jug. maître-échev. Metz* S.M.S., t.1, a.1494, 1346],
>   248).
>
> [ *DMF - Dictionnaire du Moyen Français* (1330-1500) - « *apprendre* »]

La raison en est que le mot est sorti d'usage au 17<sup>e</sup>. Et donc on l'a « exhumé » des siècles plus tard; on note en effet que « [...]*[l]e mot moderne APPRENANT est une [recréation](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/recr%C3%A9ation) (mil. XXe s.) suscitée pour traduire l'anglais [learner](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=learn) (de to learn « apprendre »), là où étudiant, élève ne conviennent qu'imparfaitement.* » (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sous dir. A. Rey, *ed. Le Robert*). Le terme anglais, quant à lui, est parfaitement usuel depuis bien longtemps et l'usage ne semble pas avoir subi d'interruption comparable.

---

Est-ce que ce genre de *recréation* est courant depuis la fin du 20<sup>e</sup> siècle et a-t-on d'autres exemples bien connus de mots avec un parcours semblable à celui du mot « *apprenant* » (sorti d'usage pendant des siècles et qui [revient](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un%20apprenant%20*%2Cun%20apprenant%2Caprenant&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cun%20apprenant%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bun%20apprenant%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20apprenant%20et%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20apprenant%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20apprenant%20qui%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20apprenant%20en%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20apprenant%20peut%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bun%20apprenant%20dans%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cun%20apprenant%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bun%20apprenant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUn%20apprenant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caprenant%3B%2Cc0) par le truchement de la terminologie au 20/21<sup>e</sup> siècle et devient de plus en plus usuel) ?

---

<sub>1. Voir aussi une [note](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8364493) de l'*OQLF* en 2002 : « Le terme *apprenant* est un générique par rapport à *élève*, *étudiant*, *écolier* et *apprenti*. Son implantation dans l'usage reflète un changement de vision de l'enseignement selon lequel l'apprenant est le premier responsable de son apprentissage et y exerce un rôle actif. Par extension, on appelle aussi *apprenant* celui qui suit un enseignement par ordinateur. » Le terme apparaît au [*Larousse*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/apprenant/4745) mais pas au *TLFi* ni à l'[Académie](http://dvlf.uchicago.edu/mot/apprenant) etc..</sub>

<sub>2. On a aussi déjà eu [*aprendre, apreneur*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/complement-godefroy/aprendre), [*aprenant(adj.), aprendement, aprendeor*(enseignant)](http://micmap.org/dicfro/previous/dictionnaire-godefroy/355/1/aprendre), [*aprenement, aprentage, aprentic, aprentise, aprentisse, aprenture*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/next/dictionnaire-godefroy/354/1/aprendre) etc. (*Godefroy*, 11-13ème).</sub>

Comment: J'aimerais bien que revive la [_sauveté_](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/sauvet%C3%A9/67293) de Littré, pour traduire correctement l'anglais _safety_, et rendre la nuance avec _sécurité_ / _sécurity_.

Comment: @mouviciel Si Littré le demandait! Je vois que c'est présent dans les toponymes i.e. la sauveté médiévale+borne de sauveté, termes associés à l'espace réservé par l'église. Ce serait bien d'avoir plus "d'espace" en effet, surtout que la sûreté est bien présente en droit civil. Merci!

Comment: Oui, j'ai l'impression que les correspondances usuelles sont _sûreté_ pour _security_ et _sécurité_ pour _safety_. Pourquoi se priver de faux-amis quand c'est possible...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pourquoi pas l'« [ordinateur](http://www.atilf.fr/spip.php?article641) », terme ancien [mis de l'avant](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinateur#.C3.89tymologie) par la société *IBM* France en 1954 pour désigner cette nouvelle réalité ?

> ORDINATEUR,
>   - TRICE, adj. et subst. masc.
>
> I. Adj.,
>   vieilli. Qui ordonne, dispose, met en ordre. Le geste humain (...)
>   renonce à prendre ; il met la chose en place et la considère ; tout est
>   spectacle pour l’homme, et même son action. Non point doux par cela seul ;
>   redoutable au contraire par cette activité ordinnatrice [sic] (ALAIN,
>   Propos, 1921, p.271).
>   Rem. On emploie de préférence auj., dans ce sens, ordonnateur, -trice.
>
> II. Subst.
>   masc.
>
> A. *LITURG*.,
>   vx. Celui qui confère le sacrement d’un ordre ecclésiastique. (Dict. XIXe
>   et XXe s.).
>
> B. *INFORMAT*. Machine
>   algorithmique composée d’un assemblage de matériels correspondant à des
>   fonctions spécifiques, capable de recevoir de l’information
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé TLFi via ATILF* - «
>   *ordinateur* »]

Comment: Merci! C'est très bien! c'est un homonyme en fait mais je n'avais jamais pensé à regarder d'autres sens que celui d'aujourd'hui. Au final c'est « l'ordinateur » qui nous sauve du « computeur »; ensuite j'ai lu  _« Jhesucrist... estoit le nouvel instituteur et ordinateur d’icelluy [baptesme]»_ . Renversant! Merci!

Comment: Les moines médiévaux connaissaient déjà le [_comput_](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comput) pour savoir quand célebrer Pâques.